# Receiving function as another function´s parameter

Tags: python-3.x, function, functional-programming

Let´s say I have 2 functions like these ones:

```
def list(n):
   l=[x for x in range(n)]
   return l
def square(l):
   l=list(map(lambda x:x**2,l))
   print(l)
```

The first one makes a list from all numbers in a given range which is "n" and the second one receives a list as a parameter and returns the squared values of this list.
However when I write:

```
square(list(20))
```

it raises the error "map object cannot be interpreted as an integer" and whenever I erase one of the functions above and run the other one it runs perfectly and I have no idea what mistake I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefined the standard function `list()`! Rename it to `my_list()` and clean the code accordingly.

As a side note, your function `list()` is doing exactly what `list(range(n))` would do. Why do you need it at all? In fact, for most purposes (including your example), `range(n)` alone is sufficient.

Finally, you do not pass a function as a parameter. You pass the value generated by another function. It is not the same.

Comment: Ok, i didnt know you could redefine the list() function and  I am aware that list(range(n)) would be simplier but I was just trying to put an example to my problem. Thanks...